# Why am I able to access a class, without specifying the containing namespace for it - C#

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

I have a question about why am I able to access a class (`Character` class), even when I am not using the `namespace` in which the class is defined?

The following is the code:

1. File `Character.cs` in project `MagicDestroyers`:

```cs
using System;
using MagicDestroyers.WeaponNS.SharpNS;
using MagicDestroyers.EnumerationNS;
using MagicDestroyers.ArmorNS.MailNS;
    
namespace MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS
{
     public class Character   
     {      
          private static int idCounter;

          private int abilityPoints;

          private int healthPoints;

          private int level;

          private int damage;

          private ChainLink bodyArmour;
          private Sword weapon;

          public ChainLink BodyArmour { get => bodyArmour; set => bodyArmour = value; }
          public Sword Weapon { get => weapon; set => weapon = value; }
          //...
          //...
          //...
     }
}
```

2. File `Melee.cs` in the same project (`MagicDestroyers`):

```cs
namespace MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS.MeleeNS
{
     //WRONG BEHAVIOR! - we are NOT "using MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS;" -

     //that is, The namespace that encompasses the Character class,

     //and, we are still able to access the Character class

     //using MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS;

     public class Melee : Character
     {

     }
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to properly format your code in [ask]. However, this is the expected behavior, `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS.MeleeNS` is a child of `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS` so you can reference all the types in `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS` and `MagicDestroyers` as if you had an `using` for them

Answer (score 2):

In this case your inner namespace `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS.MeleeNS` it's not completely unreleted with your outer one `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS`, in fact as you can see the `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS` is the parent of `MagicDestroyers.CharacterNS.MeleeNS`. This means that automatically the inner namespace inherits all the class of his father, this is the basic concept for nested namespace.

I leave you some link that I hope can clarify better:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-are-nested-namespaces-in-Chash